# Cassandra 2.2 - "nodetool repair" VS "nodetool repair -dc dc1,dc2,dc3"

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I want to completely repair a Cassandra 2.2 cluster composed of 3 datacenters (dc1, dc2, dc3) by running **only one single command line on a single node**. Do I need to run?

```
nodetool repair
```

or

```
nodetool repair -dc dc1,dc2,dc3
```

or I'm totally wrong? are those 2 commands repairing all token ranges of all cluster nodes?

Answer (score 1):

For complete repair of any Cassandra cluster, you need to run 'nodetool repair' [**on all nodes**, one by one, at least once before reaching the time specified in the gc_grace_seconds setting.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesWhen.html)

You can't repair whole cluster running repair command on one node because that node doesn't contain all data.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. but I never update or detete any row so I think I can forget about gc_grace_seconds setting (defaulting to 10 days)

Comment: Yes, then you can just run a repair on all nodes in a rolling fashion.

Comment: yes I think I will adopt this strategy to start with, thank you